# Deriving the Cauchy integral formula from the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm currently going through complex analysis, and I'm trying to grasp the concept of the whole residue theorem and so on.

I followed the derivation of the residue theorem from the Cauchy integral theorem, and I think I kind of understand what is going on there.

I thought about whether it's possible to derive the Cauchy integral **formula** from the residue theorem since I read somewhere that the integral formula is just a special case of the residue theorem.

I tried looking it up somewhere but didn't find anything.

Comment: Immediate from writing $f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)g(z)$, $g$ holomorphic.

Comment: The residue of $\frac {f(z)} {z-z_0}$ at $z_0$ is $f(z_0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!

Comment: Just a heads up: it's a good idea to do this derivation in order to better understand both the integral formula and the residue theorem. But keep in mind that from a technical point of view, this derivation is circular. You need the integral formula to prove the residue theorem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's a special case, since the residue of $g(z):=\dfrac{f(z)}{z-a}$ at $z=a$ is $f(a)$.

This is fairly trivial, but to elaborate a little, recall that $f$ is holomorphic.  So we can write $f(z)=f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)+f''(a)/2(z-a)^2+\dots$, and the residue is easy to get.

Comment: Thanks for this! Oh, I see. So if I understand this correctly, it should go as follow: $$ \oint_\Gamma g(z)= {2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^n Res_{z=z_k}g(z)$$ Now I set $g(z) := \frac{f(z)}{z-a} $ and can write $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a} = f(a)$$ Sorry if this is trivial!

Comment: Sure @markus. It is a trivial application of the residue theorem. Glad you could get it.